# How to assign multiple values from one Model into a List<T> in the ViewModel?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, list

I am new to `ASP.NET MVC`. I am trying to print a table in the view which will have the contents of `InventoryReceipts.cs` i.e.:

**Inventory.cs**

```
public class Inventory
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string DeviceType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

**InventoryReceipts.cs (Model)**

```
public class InventoryReceipts
{
    [Key]
    public int ReceiptId { get; set; }

    public string ReceiptFile { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Inventory")]
    public int InventoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Inventory Inventory { get; set; }
}
```

**InventoryViewModel.cs (ViewModel)**

```
public class InventoryViewModel
{
    ...
    public List<InventoryReceipts> Receipts { get; set; }
}
```

**View.cshtml (View)**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" id="div_ReceiptsDetails">
        <p class="c-black f-500 no-margin">Receipts Details</p>
            <div class="dtp-container" id="div_ReceiptsView">
                <table>
                    @foreach (var item in Model.Receipts)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReceiptId)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReceiptFile)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </table>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Action Method in Controller**

```
var receiptsQuery = _context.InventoryReceipts.Where(r => r.InventoryId == Id)
                                        .Select(q => new InventoryViewModel
        {
             // I need to assign the `Receipts` list with the `ReceiptFile` values of all the receipts that have the same `ReceiptsId`. But, how to write that? 
            // Something like. Receipts = Receipts.Add(q.ReceiptFile), since Receipts is a List<InventoryReceipts>. I need to assign the multiple ReceiptFile names that I retrieve from the database to this list. 
        }).ToList();
```

There will be only one entry per device in `Inventory`. For each such entry, there can be `n` number of receipts. I want to display all the `ReceiptsFile` names in a table in the `View` so that the user can know what file he uploaded/what file has already been uploaded. So basically, the `List` should contain all the names of the `Receipts` that have been uploaded for that particular device. I know that I need to retrieve the data from the `Database`, but I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I retrieved all the columns from the `Table`and assigned to a `List`. Then I assigned that `List` to `List<InventoryReceipts> Receipts`.

```
var ReceiptsObject = _context.InventoryReceipts.Where(r => r.InventoryId == Id).ToList();

inventoryObject.Receipts = ReceiptsObject;
```